# UrlTextField and CompoundPropertyModel

Tags: html, wicket

I have a wicket page, say `SignUpCustomerPage extends WebPage`. It has a default model to be `new CompoundPropertyModel<Customer>(customer)` where `customer` is private property of page class.

I add various HTML input fields into a form of page, but when adding HTML5 url input, it requires `IModel<String>` as second parameter. Example

```
model = new CompoundPropertyModel<Customer>(customer);

Form f = new Form();
f.add(new UrlTextField("website", model));
add(f);
```

Any example how to combine compound property model with URL text field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to use the `CompoundPropertyModel`. You can use `PropertyModel` instead:

```
f.add(new UrlTextField("website", new PropertyModel<String>(customer, "website"));
```

Comment: In this case, `PropertyModel<String>` must be used for all components of the form, right? Thanks!

I will consider filling an enhancement request.

Comment: I don't see why you couldn't use both actually. Mind you, I don't have much experience with CompoundPropertyModel so I could be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

You can access a property inside an object using a compoundpropertymodel using a wicket id like so: "textfieldid.property" so in the following example you can get/set the website inside the Customer object with "customer.website". this id should also be used in the html for the form input wicket:id.

```
// Customer class
public class Customer {
    private String website;
    // Getter and setter for website
}

// Webpage
public SignUpCustomerPage extends WebPage {

    private Customer customer;

    public SignUpCustomerPage() {

        customer = new Customer();

        CompoundPropertyModel<Customer> cpm = new CompoundPropertyModel<Customer>(customer);   

        Form<Customer> form = new Form("formid", cpm) {
            @Override
            public onSubmit(){ System.out.println(getModelObject().getWebsite())}
        };
        form.add(new UrlTextField("customer.website"));
        add(form);
    }
}
```

Comment: In Wicket 6.9.1 which I use currently, there is no such constructor for UrlTextField. I checked the source of Wicket 1.5.11 and it's the same thing. Which version are you using Martin?

Comment: UrlTextField does not exist in wicket, but you can create it yourself. I used UrlTextField as an example from your question. you can create an UrlTextField like so: public class UrlTextField extends TextField<String> {} and add a patternvalidator like in this example: [link](http://www.mkyong.com/wicket/wicket-password-field-example/)

Comment: I'm not the one who asked the question btw. UrlTextField does exist in the package org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form. In any case, creating a custom text field like you suggest would work. However, not creating the UrlTextField(String) constructor could simply have been an oversight in Wicket.

Comment: Ah I missed that. I see what you mean now. The constrcutor for public a textfield is: TextField(final String id){ this(id, null, null); } so maybe UrlTextField("object.property", null) works with the compoundpropertymodel. Otherwise you can can always use a PropertyModel for just one of the fields in an object and a CompoundPropertyModel for the rest. In my example new UrlTextField("customer.website", new PropertyModel(customer, "website"));